# Enabling multiple versions of Django's default form validation errors

Tags: django, django-forms

A Django form is getting two types of users: `user A` and `user B`. These users fill out a solitary text field and press the submit button.

In case the users leave the text field empty and press submit, Django's in-built `required` validation error fires.

My requirement is to have two different `required` validation errors. `User A` would see the regular `required` validation error, whereas `user B` would see the different version.

I'm unable to implement this. I passed a special argument to the `__init__` method of the form class via `self.user_type = kwargs.pop('user_type',None)`. However, I can't seem to use that to override the `required` validation error.

Why? Because here's how the `required` validation error is currently defined:

```
class TextForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required':'Please write something'})
```

I don't know how to access `self.user_type` available within `error_messages` in order to pull off what I want.

Can a more experienced developer chime in? Thanks in advance and let me know in case you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that one can actually access the `error_messages` dictionary in the `__init__` method via: `self.fields['username'].error_messages`. One can then use special arguments to differentiate the validation error along various cases, e.g.:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user_type = kwargs.pop('user_type',None)
    super(TextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['text'].error_messages = {'required': custom_validation_err_string(utype=self.user_type)}
```

`custom_validation_err_string()` simply returns the desired string given the value of `user_type`. This is quite a simple solution and scales well.